# ¿Cómo renombrar archivos con espacios utilizando sed?

Tags: linux, bash, archivo, sed

Tengo un script que me renombra todos los ficheros de un directorio que contienen el carácter "(" por el carácter "[".

```
for file in * ; do mv -v "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/(/[/g')" ; done
```

Ahora estoy construyendo un script que haga lo mismo pero renombrando todos los ficheros que contienen la cadena "] [" por la cadena "][":

```
var1=] [
var2=][
for file in * ; do mv -v "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/$var1/$var2/g')";
done
```

Pero no consigo hacerlo funcionar, imagino que por culpa de que la cadena a detectar que contiene un espacio y esto lía el uso de comillas simples y comillas dobles dentro del script. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: JBoY: te respondí, espero que te sirviera. Como eres nuevo aquí, permite que te sugiera la lectura de [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Mil gracias @fedorqui , perfectamente desarrollado. Así da gusto, no solamente se obtiene una respuesta sino que además se aprende que es lo que realmente interesa. Te comento en el desarrollo de tu respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error que tienes es que tu comando `sed` necesita comillas dobles para expandir la variable. Además, dado que estás tratando con `[` y `]`, que tienen un significado especial, debes "escaparlos" para  que sean tratados literalmente:

```
var1='\] \['  # fíjate que escaparlo y entrecomillarlo.
var2='\]\['   # si no, intenta ejecutar el comando `[`, que no existe
for file in * ;
do
    mv -v "$file" "$(echo $file | sed "s/$var1/$var2/g")";
done
```

---

A continuación elaboro posibles respuestas al problema que describes, con alternativas.

Tu aproximación a la hora de cambiar "(" por "[" funciona, si bien también podrías utilizar todo Bash, sin necesidad de utilidades externas como `sed`:

```
for file in *;
do
    mv -v "$file" "${file//\(/\[}"
done
```

- La expresión `${nombre/busco/sustituyo}` sustituye la primera ocurrencia de "busco" por "sustituyo".
- La expresión `${nombre//busco/sustituyo}` (fíjate en la doble barra después de "nombre" sustituye todas las ocurrencias de "busco" por "sustituyo".

Con un ejemplo:

```
$ f='hola(adios'
$ echo "${f/a/X}"
holX(adios
$ echo "${f//a/X}"
holX(Xdios
```

Si lo que quieres es sustituir "(" por "[", entonces debes escapar "(" porque es un carácter especial:

```
$ f='hola(adios'
$ echo "${f/\(/[}"
hola[adios
```

---

Cuando quieres reemplazar "] [" por "][", es decir eliminar el espacio entre "]" y "[" puedes usar lo mismo:

```
for file in *;
do
    mv -v "$file" "${file//] [/][}"
done
```

Fíjate en que uso comillas dobles alrededor del nombre de la variable, pues de lo contrario se expandiría a algo así como:

```
mv -v "fichero] [y tal" fichero][y tal  # ¡MAL!
```

que fallaría cuando hubiera espacios en el nombre e intentara encontrar "fichero][y", por ejemplo.

En caso que quieras hacerlo con variables, lo mismo:

```
var1='\] \['  # fíjate que escaparlo y entrecomillarlo.
var2='\]\['   # si no, intenta ejecutar el comando `[`, que no existe
for file in * ;
do
    mv -v "$file" "$(echo $file | sed "s/$var1/$var2/g")";
done
```

Fíjate que aquí la diferencia estriba en dos cosas en el comando `sed`:

- defino las variables escapando `[` y `]` con `\` para que tengan un significado literal:

  ```
  $ sed "s/] [/][/g" <<< "hola] [abc"
  sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command
  $ sed "s/\] \[/\]\[/g" <<< "hola] [abc"
  hola][abc
  ```
- uso `sed "s/....g"` en lugar de `sed 's/.../g'`. Es decir, comillas dobles en lugar de simples. ¿Por qué? Pues porque las variables solo se expanden dentro de comillas dobles:

  ```
  $ var1="hola"
  $ var2="adios"
  $ echo "hola mundo" | sed 's/$var1/$var2/g'
  hola mundo
  $ echo "hola mundo" | sed "s/$var1/$var2/g"
  adios mundo
  ```

---

Finalmente, indicar que existe la utilidad `rename` que permite hacer esto de forma mucho más fácil, condensando el bucle y `sed` todo en uno:

```
rename "s/$var1/$var2/g" $var1*
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$ touch hola1 hola2 hola3         # creo ficheros hola*
$ ls hola*                        # los veo
hola1  hola2  hola3
$ rename 's/hola/adios/' hola*    # los renombro todos
$ ls hola*                        # ¡ya no están!
ls: cannot access 'hola*': No such file or directory
$ ls adios*                       # ... porque fueron renombrados
adios1  adios2  adios3
```

Comment: El ejemplo que me facilitas:

for file in *; do mv -v "$file" "${file//] [/][}" done

Funciona correctamente! Un millón de gracias. En cambio el primer ejemplo, el de añadir comillas dobles para expandir la variable, ya lo había probado con anterioridad y me retorna un: error char 10: unterminated `s' command.

Comment: @JBoY caramba, tienes razón. Se me pasó por alto esto. He editado la respuesta para contemplar esta situación también: se trata de escapar los corchetes.

Comment: mi error principal era ese, que no escapaba los corchetes porque no los consideraba caracteres especiales :-) Muchísimas gracias una vez más por tu tiempo y dedicación. Eres un crack.